# Nice song, pity about the words

Tags: knowledge, music

There's a song I really like but I can't remember the title and I certainly can't remember the words. Perhaps you can help me.

I've summarised the lyrics as best I can, but in a rather literal way.

I'm afraid I've forgotten the first verse completely so that makes it even harder. Anyway here goes with the bit I can remember.

> Greetings! Lots of greetings! But, oops mind that hole.
>
> ---
>
> I'm not so worried now it's dark and we're all here. How about a show?
>
> My brain doesn't seem to be working, I think I'm coming down with a
>   bug.
>
> Anyway, as I said, How about a show from these two people, a
>   small creature and... Ooh I'm feeling rather...you know.
>
> ---
>
> Here's a self-contradictory statement for you.
>
> Is it my birthday? Thanks!
>
> We have everlasting togetherness.

Any help?

**Note**

It is a **very** well-known song with **many** millions of plays on Youtube--if only I could remember the title.

Comment: Not sure about  the song itself, but I *love* this concept.

Comment: Some of your word choices are questionable.  "Is it my birthday? Thanks!" is just bad for that line

Comment: What is this song all about? Can't figure any lyrics out. How do the words to it go? I wish you'd tell me, I don't know.

Comment: Why does my other comment rhyme? Not something I do all the time. (Hint: Jrveq Ny Lnaxbivp)

Comment: You could make yours an actual puzzle and (if it's useful) refer back to this one. It's your choice, after all 'Life is just a box of chocolates!'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The song is:

> Smells Like Teen Spirit, by Nirvana
>  Greetings! Lots of greetings! (Hello, hello, hello.....)
>  But, oops mind that hole. (How low)
>  I'm not so worried now it's dark (With the lights out, it's less dangerous)
>  and we're all here. How about a show? (Here we are now, entertain us)
>  My brain doesn't seem to be working, I think I'm coming down with a bug.(I feel stupid, and contagious)
>  Anyway, as I said, How about a show (here we are now, entertain us)
>  from these two people, a small creature and... Ooh I'm feeling
>  rather...you know. (a mulatto, an albino, a mosquito,  my libido)
>  Here's a contradictory statement for you. (I'm worse at what I do best)
>  Is it my birthday? Thanks! (For this gift, I feel blessed)
>  We have everlasting togetherness. (Our little group has always been and always will until the end)

Comment: In that context, that statement would be "I'm worse at what I do best"