# Can anyone help me remember the title to this song?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, music

This is related to my previous question, Q: [Nice song, pity about the words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23410/nice-song-pity-about-the-words)

I have a terrible memory for the words of songs and I'm even worse when it comes to their titles. I'd really like to find this very well-known song on Youtube, if only I could remember what it is called.

Can you help me with the title?

Here's the gist of the lyrics. I'm afraid my version is only an approximation.

*There's a possibility that my affections for you may fizzle out at some point. However, provided you remain astronomically covered there won't be any necessity for misgivings on that score -- I'll provide a guarantee of that.*

If I remember correctly, the next line starts with a religious reference about omniscience versus ignorance. However the end of the line I never heard properly at all. It might have been dog-treat related  because it sounded as though the lead singer was puzzled about how he would cope 'with a chew'?

[image]

There are a few more words after that but I can't think of them right now.

Any help?

Hint

> I've just remembered that it is quite old. It came out in the 1960s I believe. Still it has millions of plays on Youtube and was a big hit at the time. I heard a cover version on British TV only a few days ago so  it hasn't been forgotten by any means.

Here's another hint

> It may not be related to dogs, I can't be certain of that. However it certainly has some connection with domestic animals and the noises they make.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The song is

> God Only Knows, by The Beach Boys.

Explanation:

There's a possibility that my affections for you may fizzle out at some point.

> I may not always love you

However, provided you remain astronomically covered

> But long as there are stars above you

there won't be any necessity for misgivings on that score

> You never need to doubt it

I'll provide a guarantee of that.

> I'll make you so sure about it

The part about coping *with a chew* refers to

> God only knows what I'd be *without you*

The second hint points to

> Pet Sounds, the 1966 album this song is from.

Comment: The line is "God only knows what I'd be without you". "without you" can sound like "with a chew".

Comment: Yep, was about to edit that in :) The second hint points to the album name, though.